# Building Flask url in JavaScript produces empty url

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I have a table populated with JSON from an AJAX call.  Each row has a link to another Flask route.  I am able to create the rows but the urls are not pointing to the correct id, they are empty.  Why doesn't this work correctly?

```javascript
var header = tab.createTHead();
var row = header.insertRow(0);
var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
cell1.innerHTML = "<b>Col1</b>";
cell2.innerHTML = "<b>Col2</b>";

for (var i = 0; i<data.length; i++){
     var row = tab.insertRow(i+1);
     var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
     var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
     var child = data[i]['_id'];
     cell1.innerHTML = '<a href="/query/{{child}}" >' +  child + '</a>';
     cell2.innerHTML = (data[i]['similarity']).toFixed(3);
}
```

```python
@app.route("/query/<hashcode>", methods=['GET',"POST"])
@app.route("/query/", methods=['GET',"POST"])

def query(hashcode=None):
    if not hashcode == None:
       print hashcode
       sim = similarity(hashcode)
    else:
       print "None Received"
       sim = []
    return render_template('query2.html', hashcode = hashcode, sim = sim)
```

Comment: Where does `child` in the curly braces in the line `cell1.innerHTML = '<a href="/query/{{child}}" >' +  child + '</a>';` comes from?

Comment: `cell1.innerHTML = '<a href="/query/{{child}}" >' +  child + '</a>';`  change to `cell1.innerHTML = '<a href="/query/' + child + '" >' +  child + '</a>';` javascript won't parse that for you.

Comment: It works. I see now what happened. Thanks.

Comment: @fuyushimoya This should be posted as an answer (better said the answer). That line immediately caught my eye. +1

Comment: @cezar, as your opinion, I've post an answer, with some additional information, hopes that'll make my answer more resourceful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As cezar says, I'll post my comment as an answer:

In current javascript, you can't directly put something like `{{child}}` when forming a string and hope javascript notice that, and parse it to its value when creating the `string`.

So you have to do is just like what you append the child to the `text` part of the `<a>`:

```
cell1.innerHTML = '<a href="/query/' + child + '" >' + child + '</a>';
```

Notice that I say current javascript? In future ES6, you can create a string in that way, with ` notation:

```
var testStr = "test";
var aString = `this is a ${testStr}`;
```

and `aString` would be `"this is a test"` now, however, if you want to use ES6 feature at this time, you have to use some tools to help you convert code from ES6 to ES5, such as [babel](https://github.com/babel/babel)

Also,  you can learn the ES6 features at some sites: [github-es6features](https://github.com/lukehoban/es6features), [ECMAScript 6 — New Features: Overview & Comparison](http://es6-features.org/#Constants)